# Can TypeScript iterate over an interface's "own" keys only?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there any way to build a `DeepRequired<T>`-like  helper type that would only affect keys that are not "external" to `T` ?

What I mean is, with this sample code:

```js
interface Test{
  prop1?: string
  prop2: {
    prop3?: {
      prop3b?: HTMLElement
    }
    prop4?: number
  }
}

declare const test: DeepRequired<Test>
const c: HTMLElement = test.prop2.prop3.prop3b
```

This will fail on `c` with the error:

> Type '{ accessKey: string; readonly accessKeyLabel: string; autocapitalize: string; dir: string; draggable: boolean; hidden: boolean; innerText: string; lang: string; readonly offsetHeight: number; ... 233 more ...; focus: (options?: FocusOptions | undefined) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'HTMLElement'.

Which, if I understand correctly, is because `prop3b?: HTMLElement` has been transformed to `prop3b: DeepRequired<HTMLElement>`.

Is there any way to be "deep but shallow" ?

I have tried building my own recursive type, something simple like:

```js
type IsObject<T> = T extends AnyArray
  ? false
  : T extends object
  ? true
  : false

type RRequired<T> = {
  [P in keyof T]-?: NonNullable<T[P]> extends Builtin
    ? T[P]
    : NonNullable<T[P]> extends AnyArray
    ? T[P]
    : IsObject<NonNullable<T[P]>> extends true
    ? RRequired<T[P]>
    : T[P]
}
```

... but I cannot find a way to stop the recursion.

My understanding is that to TypeScript, my `Test` interface is equivalent to:

```js
interface Test{
  prop1?: string
  prop2: {
    prop3?: {
      prop3b?: {
        ...HTMLElement
      }
    }
    prop4?: number
  }
}
```

i.e. all `HTMLElement`'s properties (or any other type/interface) inlined within my type where I use them... so I don't know how to discriminate between nested properties of my interface and those of an "external", non-builtin type.

So, is there any way to write a `RRequired<T>` type that would transform `Test` to the following?

```js
RRequired<Test> == {
  prop1: string
  prop2: {
    prop3: {
      prop3b: HTMLElement // <- preserve HTMLElement
    }
    prop4: number
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only way to achieve something like this is to check against a list of "allowed types" that you don't want to make deeply required. E.g.

```
type DeepRequired<T> = T extends HTMLElement ? T : {
    [K in keyof T]-?: DeepRequired<T[K]>
}
```

or

```
type AllowedTypes = HTMLElement | WhateverTypeYouWantToAllow | ...
type DeepRequired<T> = T extends AllowedTypes ? T : {
    [K in keyof T]-?: DeepRequired<T[K]>
}
```

But we aware that this checks if the structure matches. Meaning that if you have a type with a shape exactly like `HTMLElement` or any element in your `AllowedTypes` that is *of a similar shape* the condition will short-circuit and give you not the wanted result. Here type `Bogus` is similar to everything in `Test.prop2`, meaning that everything below `prop2` won't be required

```
type Bogus = {
    prop4?: number;
}

type AllowedTypes = HTMLElement | Bogus;

type DeepRequired<T> = T extends AllowedTypes ? T : {
    [K in keyof T]-?: DeepRequired<T[K]>
}

declare const z: DeepRequired<Test>
z.prop2.prop3.prop3b // BOOM, prop3 is optional!
```

Since HTMLElement and all its subtypes are very complex shapes, you most likely will get very far with that approach. But in a structural typed type system, the shape is everything, and with that comes some gotchas.

Comment: Thanks @ddprrt! I was "afraid" it might come to this... I was toying with an idea earlier: having a `Preserve<T>` type I could use, like `Preserve<HTMLElement>`, to mark types that I do not want to recurse into. Would there be a way to swap the check on `AllowedTypes` with a check on `Preserve`? Would `T extends Preserve<infer P> ? P : ...` ? Gonna try that

Comment: Oh and I guess you meant that `z.prop2.prop4` is optional?

Comment: No, even z.prop2.prop3 is optional, because `Bogus` extends Test.prop2. Still a sub-type!

There is a way to do a Preserve type: Read up on Opaque type techniques in TypeScript: https://codemix.com/opaque-types-in-javascript/ -- however, it involves a nasty typecast at some point that you won't get around.

Comment: Yes that's indeed the opaque type I saw in ts-essential that gave me the idea. What do you mean about the typecast? I managed to do this, with type inference I can "resolve" the `Preserve<T>` down to `T`: https://tsplay.dev/zwO96m – is there something I'm missing that will bite me down the road?

Comment: Just something to be aware of: If you ever are going to construct an object of type `Test`, you will have to cast the element that you're passing at prop3b to `Preserved<HTMLElement`> (or one of its subtypes. E.g.: https://tsplay.dev/PmLPZm

Comment: Yeah I came to that realization indeed. What about a first level of "blueprint"? https://tsplay.dev/4w1vYN
It's slightly more verbose on the declaration side, but better to use? `Preserve` does not seem to work well with `Preserve<HTMLElement | null>` however: https://tsplay.dev/DWKDMw